# Breaking Angular2 RC1 Cache on Page Refresh with HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Encountering an interesting issue with angular2 and the HashLocationStrategy.  I implemented the `hashlocationstrategy` in my `boot.ts` like so:

```
provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
```

And now my URLs have the # in them which is fine.  And now when I refresh it no longer has a 404 error but a different error in reloading the index.html.  What's happening is a properties service I have written is not correctly populating my application properties on a refresh.  It works just fine however if I open up chrome developer tools and tick the checkbox for "Disable cache".  Works also if I simply clear my cache and then do a refresh.  It seems like the properties are getting cleared out on refresh with the HachLocationStrategy but the cache thinks that they are still there.  So when my app loads index.html again, I get an error that the properties are null and get various errors like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'logGroup' of null(…)
```

Is there a way to force a browser cache clear on refresh?  I have added some meta tags to my index.html such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

And when I try and get the RunTimeCompiler to clear the template cache I get an error that it cannot find that class.  Open to any suggestions.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome/Firefox/IE doesn't matter happens in all of em.

Comment: I actually fixed it by adding an extra variable and wrapping my app with an *ngIf to wait for the properties to be loaded.  When they are loaded, the variable is set to true and the rest of the html is loaded.  Not perfect, but it works for now.